# Curl command to get all pipelines for a project in Gitlab

Tags: git, rest, curl, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is there a gitlab rest api command to get **all** pipelines for a project in gitlab? The current one I tried only gives me this month's pipeline ids.

Here's the command I did (following the doc https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html):

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your gitlab access token>" "https://<your gitlab url>/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/pipelines"
```

But it only has returned pipelines in this past month but I want all pipelines since the projects existance (see the **created_at** fields in the json response that only show pipelines for this month of June):

> [   {
> "id": 64056,
> "project_id": 260,
> "sha": "ee38d9b75...c48a5e09d59ab",
> "ref": "Story-C",
> "status": "success",
> "**created_at**": "2023-06-30T19:18:48.678Z",
> "updated_at": "2023-06-30T19:19:39.619Z",
> "web_url": "https://test.gitlab.com/myproject/aa/Project1/-/pipelines/64178"   },
> {
> "id": 64055,
> "project_id": 260,
> "sha": "a16d08bf9e....6644b888f86bb",
> "ref": "Story-C",
> "status": "success",
> "**created_at**": "2023-06-30T18:59:23.613Z",
> "updated_at": "2023-06-30T19:07:19.710Z",
> "web_url": "https://test.gitlab.com/myproject/aa/Project1/-/pipelines/64176"   },
> {
> "id": 64054,
> "project_id": 260,
> "sha": "37abc11....2d314b9d04b71f",
> "ref": "Story-B",
> "status": "failed",
> "**created_at**": "2023-06-30T18:21:39.214Z",
> "updated_at": "2023-06-30T18:22:20.776Z",
> "web_url": "https://test.gitlab.com/myproject/aa/Project1/-/pipelines/64174"   },
> {
> "id": 64053,
> "project_id": 260,
> "sha": "37085619....b416591bc25c61",
> "ref": "Story-B",
> "status": "success",
> "**created_at**": "2023-06-30T17:35:15.761Z",
> "updated_at": "2023-06-30T17:36:10.963Z",
> "web_url": "https://test.gitlab.com/myproject/aa/Project1/-/pipelines/64173"   },
> {
> "id": 64052,
> "project_id": 260,
> "sha": "f1ae944c......a935821a6",
> "ref": "master",
> "status": "success",
> "**created_at**": "2023-06-30T14:41:42.554Z",
> "updated_at": "2023-06-30T14:42:26.583Z",
> "web_url": "https://test.gitlab.com/myproject/aa/Project1/-/pipelines/64172"   },
> {
> "id": 64051,
> "project_id": 260,
> "sha": "9e80dafc......e2b6222679c6",
> "ref": "Story-A",
> "status": "success",
> "**created_at**": "2023-06-30T14:39:03.073Z",
> "updated_at": "2023-06-30T14:39:53.794Z",
> "web_url": "https://test.gitlab.com/myproject/aa/Project1/-/pipelines/64171"   },
> {
> "id": 64050,
> "project_id": 260,
> "sha": "d31c96bad......1446a3e67a8fa3",
> "ref": "Story-A",
> "status": "success",
> "**created_at**": "2023-06-30T14:32:19.431Z",
> "updated_at": "2023-06-30T14:33:21.138Z",
> "web_url": "https://test.gitlab.com/myproject/aa/Project1/-/pipelines/64170"   },
> {
> "id": 64049,
> "project_id": 260,
> "sha": "746073226....af93aa06269f",
> "ref": "Story-A_logging",
> "status": "success",
> "**created_at**": "2023-06-28T15:13:18.343Z",
> "updated_at": "2023-06-28T15:14:08.113Z",
> "web_url": "https://test.gitlab.com/myproject/aa/Project1/-/pipelines/64145"   },
> {
> "id": 64048,
> "project_id": 260,
> "sha": "6c1a5e00a6....de9258c685383",
> "ref": "Story-A_logging",
> "status": "success",
> "**created_at**": "2023-06-20T14:25:26.167Z",
> "updated_at": "2023-06-20T14:32:29.525Z",
> "web_url": "https://test.gitlab.com/myproject/aa/Project1/-/pipelines/64101"   },
> {
> "id": 64047,
> "project_id": 260,
> "sha": "871258abbc....e825406fd8ce",
> "ref": "Story-A",
> "status": "success",
> "**created_at**": "2023-06-13T15:41:52.916Z",
> "updated_at": "2023-06-13T15:42:42.485Z",
> "web_url": "https://test.gitlab.com/myproject/aa/Project1/-/pipelines/64068"   },
> {
> "id": 64046,
> "project_id": 260,
> "sha": "6a2be8fced....216f7cffd2",
> "ref": "Story-A",
> "status": "success",
> "**created_at**": "2023-06-08T19:49:42.212Z",
> "updated_at": "2023-06-12T15:49:00.510Z",
> "web_url": "https://test.gitlab.com/myproject/aa/Project1/-/pipelines/64048"   },
> {
> "id": 64045,
> "project_id": 260,
> "sha": "57a88d64......1942f2475824",
> "ref": "Story-A",
> "status": "success",
> "**created_at**": "2023-06-08T16:15:18.815Z",
> "updated_at": "2023-06-08T16:17:15.850Z",
> "web_url": "https://test.gitlab.com/myproject/aa/Project1/-/pipelines/64047"   },
> {
> "id": 64044,
> "project_id": 260,
> "sha": "b6b455....7568c541653e",
> "ref": "Story-A",
> "status": "success",
> "**created_at**": "2023-06-08T15:56:15.097Z",
> "updated_at": "2023-06-08T15:57:26.963Z",
> "web_url": "https://test.gitlab.com/myproject/aa/Project1/-/pipelines/64046"   },
> {
> "id": 64043,
> "project_id": 260,
> "sha": "8f212....57baaddc091a",
> "ref": "Story-A",
> "status": "success",
> "**created_at**": "2023-06-07T20:04:33.353Z",
> "updated_at": "2023-06-07T20:05:41.616Z",
> "web_url": "https://test.gitlab.com/myproject/aa/Project1/-/pipelines/64043"   },
> {
> "id": 64042,
> "project_id": 260,
> "sha": "0c9113eb1......b1efbf628ea9a",
> "ref": "Story-A",
> "status": "success",
> "**created_at**": "2023-06-07T19:53:33.848Z",
> "updated_at": "2023-06-07T19:55:02.234Z",
> "web_url": "https://test.gitlab.com/myproject/aa/Project1/-/pipelines/64042"   },
> {
> "id": 64041,
> "project_id": 260,
> "sha": "e123007a14ec89aa4......b0c41800b",
> "ref": "Story-A",
> "status": "success",
> "**created_at**": "2023-06-07T19:42:09.780Z",
> "updated_at": "2023-06-07T19:46:37.742Z",
> "web_url": "https://test.gitlab.com/myproject/aa/Project1/-/pipelines/64041"   },
> {
> "id": 64040,
> "project_id": 260,
> "sha": "7f85108cc......21420ba",
> "ref": "Story-A",
> "status": "success",
> "**created_at**": "2023-06-07T18:41:33.447Z",
> "updated_at": "2023-06-07T18:43:07.849Z",
> "web_url": "https://test.gitlab.com/myproject/aa/Project1/-/pipelines/64040"   }
> ]

Comment: The API is [paginated](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/rest/#pagination). By default, 20 results are returned for most endpoints. You need to call the next page to get more results.

Comment: Thanks @sytech you're right, I just tested it and it worked.  Do add that as the answer so I can mark it so.

Answer (score 0):

As @sytech mentioned in his response, the answer is that the api is paginated.

This will just get the latest 20 entries.

> curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: "
> "https:///api/v4/projects/<project_id>/pipelines"

But the link he provided https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/rest/#pagination requires that you add more parameters to the api to get more data from the past.

Knowing this I added `?page=x` where `x` is any page number such as 2, 3, or 10  or more.

So the api call is now:

> curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: "
> "https:///api/v4/projects/<project_id>/pipelines?page=4"

Also the link shows we can use a `per_page=x` parameter where you can define it to up to 100 items returned per request, so that api call would be:

> curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: "
> "https:///api/v4/projects/<project_id>/pipelines?per_page=100"